# How to simplify multiple JSON-Schema switch-like statements

Tags: json, jsonschema

There is an example of a switch-like condition in the JSON Schema documentation.

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html

I have added two more countries to the example, which both should have the same postal code patterns as Netherlands. I can get this example to work with two additional `if/then` structures, but it becomes messy when more items are to be added.

Is there DRYer version, e.g. like the hypothetical one below?

```
"properties": { "country": { "const": ["Netherlands", "Upperlands", "Lowerlands" } }
```

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "street_address": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "country": {
      "enum": ["United States of America", "Canada", "Netherlands",
              "Upperlands","Lowerlands"]
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": { "country": { "const": "United States of America" } }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": { "postal_code": { "pattern": "[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?" } }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": { "country": { "const": "Canada" } }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": { "postal_code": { "pattern": "[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]" } }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": { "country": { "const": "Netherlands" } }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": { "postal_code": { "pattern": "[0-9]{4} [A-Z]{2}" } }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the enum pattern instead. It's less verbose and easier to read, but the error messages you get are terrible, so I suggest you stick with the if/then pattern. Here's what using the enum pattern would look like.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "street_address": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "country": {
      "enum": ["United States of America", "Canada", "Netherlands",
               "Upperlands","Lowerlands"]
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "country": { "const": "United States of America" },
        "postal_code": { "pattern": "[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?" }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "country": { "const": "Canada" },
        "postal_code": { "pattern": "[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]" }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "country": { "const": "Netherlands" },
        "postal_code": { "pattern": "[0-9]{4} [A-Z]{2}" }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Although there isn't good way around the verbosity, there is something you can do to improve readability/maintainability. You can use definitions to hide the verbose parts.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "street_address": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "country": {
      "enum": ["United States of America", "Canada", "Netherlands",
               "Upperlands","Lowerlands"]
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/validate-us-postal-code" },
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/validate-ca-postal-code" },
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/validate-nl-postal-code" }
  ]
  "definitions": {
    "validate-us-postal-code": {
      "if": {
        "properties": { "country": { "const": "United States of America" } }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": { "postal_code": { "pattern": "[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?" } }
      }
    },
    "validate-ca-postal-code": {
      "if": {
        "properties": { "country": { "const": "Canada" } }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": { "postal_code": { "pattern": "[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]" } }
      }
    },
    "validate-nl-postal-code": {
      "if": {
        "properties": { "country": { "const": "Netherlands" } }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": { "postal_code": { "pattern": "[0-9]{4} [A-Z]{2}" } }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This allows someone to be able to understand everything this schema does just by reading the first few lines. The verbose/complicated stuff is pushed to the bottom where you don't have to deal with it if you don't need to.

Comment: Mmm.. not very inviting (but thanks anyway). I have worked with XML Schema before, where it is slightly less messy.